# Live stream microphone using python and play it on a web browser or through android media player

Tags: python, android-studio, streaming

i am not very familiar with python.
my goal is to stream microphone audio using python and receive and play it on an android app.

after hours of searching I've found some python codes that do this using socket and it's working but I was not able to find any tutorial about how to catch that stream on android app side and play it.
here is one of the socket stream code:

```py
import pyaudio
import socket
import select

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 4096

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(('', 4444))
serversocket.listen(5)


def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    for s in read_list[1:]:
        s.send(in_data)
    return (None, pyaudio.paContinue)


# start Recording
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK, stream_callback=callback)
# stream.start_stream()

read_list = [serversocket]
print ("recording...")

try:
    while True:
        readable, writable, errored = select.select(read_list, [], [])
        for s in readable:
            if s is serversocket:
                (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
                read_list.append(clientsocket)
                print ("Connection from"), address
            else:
                data = s.recv(1024)
                if not data:
                    read_list.remove(s)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass


print ("finished recording")

serversocket.close()
# stop Recording
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()
```

my problem is that i want to get a stream url with an output file at the end of it like:
http://192.168.1.3:4444/out.mp3

using vlc cli i can do it easily:

```
cvlc -vvv alsa://plughw:1 --sout '#transcode{acodec=mp3,ab=16,channels=1,scodec=none}:standard{access=http,dst=0.0.0.0:8888/out.mp3}'
```

but i do want to use vlc for some reason and not know how to achieve this on python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `os.system('insert command here')` from os module. It will execute the argument in system terminal.

You can just run the cvlc using your python script